# React Native - Tesseract.js - Error: Cannot create URL for blob

Tags: javascript, react-native, tesseract.js

I am having a problem using the [Tesseract.js](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js) libary in an React Native App (on the Android Platform). I am currently taking a picture with in the App, saving the image information in a `base64 string` and trying to pass it the the `worker.recognize()` function. The string passed to the function is built as followed: `data:image/jpeg;base64,MY_BASE64_STRING`. I also tried passing a URL to an image and also tried using the absolute path to an image file I'm always getting the same error:

> Error: Cannot create URL for blob!

Here is the code I am using for version 2.0.0-alpha.13:

```
const { TesseractWorker } = Tesseract
const worker = new TesseractWorker({
    workerPath: '../../../node_modules/tesseract.js/dist/worker.min.js',
    langPath: '../../assets/lang',
    corePath: '../../../node_modules/tesseract.js-core/tesseract-core.wasm.js',
    })

worker
    .recognize(`data:image/jpeg;base64,${data.base64}`)
    .progress(info => {
        console.log(info)
    })
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result.text)
    })
```

I tried using Versions [1.0.19](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tesseract.js) and the alpha version [2.0.0-alpha.13](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tesseract.js/v/2.0.0-alpha.13)

Thank you to you all! ♥

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tesseract.js doesn't support react-native according to this issue.

https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/issues/55

Use this library which uses native mobile modules instead. Might not work with expo though

https://github.com/jonathanpalma/react-native-tesseract-ocr